# How to Dispose SharpDX objects

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, sharpdx

After searching on the net I'm totally confused about disposing sharpdx objects. I don't know how should I dispose them.
Should I dispose them like unmanaged resources?
Does my app creates memory leak if I don't dispose them?
do sharpdx classes already override finalizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they can lead to memory leaks if they are not disposed.

Have a look at this article:

http://english.r2d2rigo.es/2014/09/18/proper-lifecycle-management-of-sharpdx-resources-in-cxaml-universal-apps/

Also you can implement Idisposable interface to your class and manually dispose your objects.

Comment: thanks. one more thing. does disposing them in finalizer enough to prevent memory leaks? should I use Utilities.Dispose or Dispose on the object itself?

Comment: calling dispose method on your object should be enough. Avoid using finalizers as it may slow down the garbage collection process.

Comment: thanks. but as I know there is no way to dispose objects automatically without finalizer. Am I right?

Comment: yes if it is an unmanaged resource you will need to use finalizer. however if the object has inherited the Idisposible interface you should be able to dispose it by called the <your_object>.dispose() method.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: So I actually have to implement Idisposable and call Dispose manually, and use finalizer in case of forgetting to call Dispose.